# How to loop through a string by space? How do i know the index no of the word i currently am on in the string?

Tags: c++, string

This code that i have written loops through a string char by char. What i want is to loop through a string word by word. Here is my code.

```
string a; // already declared
   // c is string array
for (i=0;i<b;i++) {
    if (strcmp (c[i],a[i]) == 0 ) {
      // do something
       }
     }
```

Comment: You don't need `strcmp` to compare characters. Just use `c[i]==a[i]`.

Comment: i want to compare strings not characters, that is why i would like to loop through the whole string word by word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use string-streams:

```
string a = "hello   my name    is    joe";
stringstream s(a);
string word;
// vector<string> c = ... ;

for (int i = 0; s >> word; i++)
{
    if (word == c[i])
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

If you want to have the ability to go front and back in words, you should store them in an array, so this second code is useful for that:

```
string a = "hello   my name    is    joe";
vector<string> c = {"hello","my","name","is","joe"};
string word;
vector<string> words;

for (stringstream s(a); s >> word; )
    words.push_back(word);

for (int i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
{
    if (words[i] == c[i])
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: @M M. how might i get the index no of the word i am on during the time of comparison?

Comment: keep a count and increment it every loop iteration

Comment: @Frontenderman what if i want to iterate back to some position back in the string?

Comment: That might get a little tricky. Can you be a little more specific? If you'd want to go back to specific words consistently then you might want to save each word in an array.

Comment: @Frontenderman the words that i may want to go back to will be totally random(depends on the string input by the user and various other conditions), and i may only have the index no as a reference. The words in the string are not unique, so i cant just go and compare the word and then go back to it.

Comment: I can't really answer without more information. When will you want to go back? Will you only have the index you want to go back to or will there be a way to get the position of the word you want to go back to if they are stored in an array in the order they show up in? If you will only have the index then you may want to store an array of pairs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/ where one of the values could be the word's start index and the other value can be the actual string for that word

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sort(int *,int);

int word_size(char * in, int length)
{
    int size = 0;
    if(!strcmp(in,""))
        size = 1;

    for(int i =0 ;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(in[i] == ' ')
            size ++;
    }

    return size;
}

int get_word_size(char * in,int length, int index)
{
    int word_num = 0;
    int size = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(in[i] == ' ')
            word_num++;
        else if(word_num == index)
        {
            size++;
        }
    }
    return size;
}

char * get_word(char * in,int length,int index)
{
    char * result = new char[get_word_size(in,length,index)];
    int k = 0;
    int word_num = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(in[i] == ' ')
            word_num++;
        else if(word_num == index)
        {
            result[k] = in[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char * x = "Hello this is my name";


    char * y = "byebye that was your name";



    char * outChar = get_word(x,21,3);
    outChar[get_word_size(x,21,2)] = '\0';
    cout << outChar;

    int a;
    cin>>a;
    return 0;
}
```

Just tested it...

Comment: What is this abomination? It's certainly not idiomatic C++.