# filling a two dimensional array with characters

Tags: c++

I'm trying to fill a 2 dimensional array with characters. I have the following code and it seems to work, but not correctly. So the problem is it fills the entire array with '.' characters. What seems to be my issue? How come each "word" is not on it's own row?

```
char Table[10][50];
char block[100] = "the cat and the hat.";
int pos = 0;

while (pos < StrLen(block)) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 50; y++) {
            Table[i][y] = block[pos];
        }
    }
    pos++;
}

cout << Table[0][0] << " " << Table[0][1] << " " << Table[0][2] << endl;
cout << Table[1][0] << " " << Table[1][1] << " " << Table[1][2] << endl;
```

Results

```
. . . .
. . . .
```

Comment: You increment `pos` only after the for-loops completed filling the entire array. So you first fill all array positions with `block[0]`, then override them with `block[1]`, and so on. Finally you override them all with `block[strlen(block)-1]`, which is `'.'`.

Comment: Think about it a bit. How many times are you setting `table[0][0]`?

Comment: Where in the above code are you making any effort to find the 'words' in `block`? If you want to find words then somewhere you have to look for the spaces that separate the words.

Comment: obviously you're starting from your first char in you sentence and putting each char in all of the elements in your 2D array, i.e. you put`t` in there all, after that you replace it with `h` and so on until you end up with `.`

Comment: It would be convenient if you posted your expected output.

Comment: Wouldn't any flavor of strcpy-like routine be easier & more convenient?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like this I think:

```
char Table[10][50];
char block[1000] = "the cat and the hat.";
int pos = 0;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;

while (pos < strLen(block)) {
    if(block[pos] == ' ')
    {
      table[row][col] = '\0';
      row++;
      col = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      table[row][col] = block[pos];
      col++;
    }
    }
    pos++;
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887232/how-to-loop-through-a-string-by-space-how-do-i-know-the-index-no-of-the-word-i/19887488#19887488) link could also help you.

Comment: The OP says he wants to separate out the words.

Comment: Yes,changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
for (int pos = 0; pos < strlen(block); ++pos)
{
    if (block[pos] == ' ')
    {
        Table[row][col] = '\0'; // make sure each row is null terminated
        ++row;                  // move to the next row
        col = 0;                // starting at column zero
    }
    else
    {
        Table[row][col] = block[pos];
        ++col;
    }
}
```

Untested code.

Unlike your code it does look for spaces in the input, which if you think about it, is pretty much required to separate text into words.

Answer (score 0):

Because everytime iterating the outer 'while' loop, it will overwrite 'Table[i][y]', move away the outer loop and make the following modification.

```
char Table[10][50];
char block[1000] = "the cat and the hat.";
int pos = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 10 && i<strlen(block); i++) {
   for(int y = 0; y < 50; y++) {
       Table[i][y] = block[pos];       
    }
    pos++;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what your code does and why you think it's an improvement over the original code? Notice also that in your code `pos` is redundant. It could be replaced with `i`.

Comment: I thought he wants to filling each row with a character in the string. As he said 'How come each "word" is not on it's own row', which in this case the 'word' seems to mean character, as the original code does nothing about the separator between words.